# Looking for a template which reference paper has a title

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I guess this question has been asked several times but still I did not find a solution :(

I used the template for physical review A, `\bibliographystyle{spphys}`, which the reference paper only has author name, journal title, volume, page e.g.

> XXX, Phys. Rev. Lett. XX, XX (XXXX)

I need a template that could display the title of the quoted paper.  e.g.

> XXX, title, Phys. Rev. Lett. XX, XX (XXXX)

Where can I find such a template? and/or `bst` file?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Almost all the bibliographic BibTeX styles show the article title. You must have many already installed in you TeX distribution. Try  simply to change `spphys` with `plain`or `alpha`, `vancouver`, `chicago`, etc.

Comment: Same problem. I think there is a bug on spphys or something not clear on the journal template. I would have prefer to make work the recommanded citation package instead of using other like plain, alpha...

Comment: No, it's not a bug. In physics journals it's very common to omit the paper titles in the bibliography.

Comment: @Fran Would you add an answer?

Comment: @egreg That's done!

Comment: @Dilaton, Thanks a lot! Seems I don't need to backup all the solution to my questions :-)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the bibliographic BibTeX styles show the article title. You must have many of them already installed in you TeX distribution. Try simply to change `spphys` with `plain` or `alpha`, `vancouver`, `chicago` etc. For a complete list of available styles in you hard disk, you only need search files with `.bst` extension.

Help for [Choosing a BibTeX Style](http://web.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html) by examples can be obtained of the Web [here](https://verbosus.com/bibtex-style-examples.html) and [there](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html).Or you can search those that meet your requirements playing with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
 An interesting citation 
 \cite{IEEEexample:article_typical}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{IEEEexample}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]