# What is the simplest way of referencing papers in latex?

Tags: thesis

I am new with Texmaker. After reading many pages it is unclear what is the simplest way of referencing papers.

The questions that should be helpful for me are:

1)Is there any simple way of referencing papers?

2)Is it ok to use texmaker for that or there is some extra software to do that?

For example, once a I about heard Zotero, but i do not know if it can be used with texmaker.

3)Any place with helpulf information to learn about how to reference papers?

Any example of referencing a paper will be welcome.

Comment: The recommended way is to write a bibliography database in the form of `.bib` file and use `biblatex` + `biber`. An excellent tool to create such files is with the multiplatform software `JabRef`.

Comment: This question is about reference management and therefore off-topic.  Perhaps you might want to ask this on [Academia.SX](https://academia.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't think it is clear this is off-topic at all. It is probably a duplicate and certainly too broad. Possibly opinion-based. But certainly not off-topic. As I read the question, it is about how to do this *in LaTeX*. It isn't about how to reference in general.

Comment: It's perfectly possible to maintain your .bib files with texmaker. They're text files just like your .tex files. I don't use texmaker but use a text editor for both tex and bib files. Many of the tools seem to cause more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any simple way of referencing papers?

There are [three simple ways](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) to do that.

> there is some extra software to do that?

Any text editor is enough to make/edit a reference database in BibTeX format (files with `.bib` extension) as the References,bib showed in above the limked answer.

Said that, there are several tools that in some way or another help you with this tasks. This include several LaTeX editors because the syntax highlighting or something else, bust mostly to specific tools for management of bibliographic references.

One of the best tools is effectively Zotero. Try also Mendeley, `kbibtex` (if you use Linux) and of course JabRef (I usually use this), but there are others as `bibus`, even in text mode as `bibcursed` (Linux).

> Any place with helpful information to learn about how to reference papers?

Basic use of BibteX is explained in almost any LaTex book and Internet LaTeX tutorials. See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner)

Of course, this site is also a good place to learn. Start with the most upvoted quuestion of the related tags as "bibtex". For instance, if you want to use biblatex start with 
[bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) and [What to do to switch to biblatex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex)  and [Guidelines for customizing biblatex styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12806/guidelines-for-customizing-biblatex-styles), etc.

> Any example of referencing a paper will be welcome.

Already done, but only in this site you can find hundreds (may be thousands) of additionals examples. Just search them.