# Recommended symbols for footnotes

Tags: footnotes, thesis, report

Footnotes are added as `\footnote{footnote_here}`. It produces a number as hyperlink to the footnote, at least as default. The **problem** is that, when citing bibliography, those symbols interfere each other; I mean, citations and footnotes have a number as symbol..

**Question**

Is there any recommended symbol for footnotes different from arabic numbers?
How can I modify it?

Comment: Take a look at the `footmisc` package. You can have a series of symbols, or lowercase letters, for instance. Depending on the number of footnotes you have, you might consider restting the footnote counter at each page.

Comment: Citation with superscript numbers are not very usual. If possible, wouldn't it be better change the citation style? I mean to an author-year style, or at least, to  the standard inline  `[1]` (this hardly might be confused with a superscript small number without brackets).

Comment: @Fran, thanks for the comment :). Maybe you are right, I have read lot of papers with superscripts..Is there any easy way to change that? I like brackets to cite, as you put it

Comment: Yes, very easy. See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) for a very basic introduction with some examples.

Comment: I have a huge disorder in the preamble, @Fran. I understood your answer but I am not totally sure about changing my preamble..thanks anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use letters for footnotes:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}% for dummy text

\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext\footnote{foo}
\blindtext\footnote{bar}
\end{document}
```