# How to use bib file in tex?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Good evening everybody, excuse me for such question, but i totally dont understand how to use .bib file for references in article, can somebody explain me step by step moves, how to include the file so that my WINEDT will see it and use it ? How to create bib file properly. Which folder should i put it ? Thank you

Comment: You should start by looking at some of the results from [Googling "how to use bibtex"](https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+use+bibtex).

Comment: [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) solve your doubts?

Comment: Is it similar way as .bib file? - i dont sure at all i should include it, but i have latex error like I found no \bibdata command---while reading file SERIES REPRESENTATION REVISED.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file SERIES REPRESENTATION REVISED.aux

Comment: the answer pointed out by @Fran has more than one block of example code.  you need a `\bibliographystyle` command; the one in the cited example is `\bibliographystyle{plain}`.  add that along with your `\bibliography{<filename>}` directive and the necessary information will be placed in the `.aux` file.  then `bibtex` must be run separately, and latex two more times to resolve the references.

Comment: I made a video tutorial (BibLaTeX / Texmaker): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZYvS52511oQ. I guess that this is more helpful in the beginning. And consider the recommendation from Werner.

Comment: I added a very related question. Since you seem to be a beginner, consider using BibLaTeX right from the start.

Comment: @KolosovPetro My link show three methods to include bibliography. The first one without using any external .bib file, the other two using a .bib file that you can write yourself with a simple text editor or with the help of programs  as JabRef (much easier). Save the examples showed in a test directory and try to compile these examples before of trying with your real documents. Left the example .bib file in the same directory that the example .tex file and then compile following the four steps showed in 2nd and 3th method.

Comment: @Fran yes, i did everything like you told, seems i compile wrong - in preambula i put \bibliography{mybib}
\bibliographystyle{plain} and 
file in same directory as .tex file

Comment: In the preamble?! That is wrong: Try exactly as showed in the examples.

Comment: I cant find how to compile in bibtex my_bib - it's not present in the list

Comment: Miracle! it's working ! thanks to everybody who helped !!

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is to have  .bib files in the working folder (the folder of the .tex file). You must run `(pdf)latex` on the main file then `bibtex` (or, better, `biber`), then again `(pdf)latex` (twice).

To avoid syntax errors, it's better to  create your .bib file with a dedicated tool like `JabRef` available [here](http://www.jabref.org/#downloads) (requires Java).

Last point: on  the `Configuration Components` page of `WinEdt.org`, you can find some useful add-ons, among which [JabRef](http://www.winedt.org/config.html) which adds a JabRef icon in the toolbar and an entry in the `Accessories` menu, which will give you a direct access to JabRef from within WinEdt.

Comment: I used my .bib file, adeed it to preambula like \bibliography{my_bib}
\bibliographystyle{plain}, then no reference appears anyway, what is wrong ?

Comment: It's rather vague. If you ran the compilers as I said, it should work. Do you have a `.blg` file?  (it the .log file for bibliographies).  You should post a minimal code  reproducing the problem

Comment: @KolosovPetro Don't add these commands in the preamble, but at the point in your document, where you want the bibliography to appear. You'll also have to cite at least one entry.

Comment: Miracle! it's working ! thanks to everybody who helped !!