# Problems creating my bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I am provided a template and now I want to print my bibliography.
The template comes with a LaTeX-class file, which contains the entry: 
`\usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=ieee,sorting=none,dateabbrev=false,urldate=comp]{biblatex}`

In the .tex file after some specifications such as `\documentclass{myTemplte}`, there is the entry `\addbibresource{./library.bib}`. Now, here is how I try to create one quotation:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \def\svgwidth{\linewidth}
    \import{pic/}{someFigure.pdf_tex}
    \caption{Description, source: \cite{2018}.}
    \label{Figure}
\end{figure}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

Now, instead of a nice [1], the bibtexkey `2018` appears and the bibliography doesn't get printed at all. Can anyone think of a reason for this? Or is this question stupid to ask, because it cannot be recreated?

By the way, I am using JabRef to create my entries in my .bib file. For this particular source, I am using:

```
@Online{2018,
  title = {Open Clip Art},
  date  = {2018-07-12},
  url   = {https://openclipart.org/},
}
```

When I run the "Bibliography" command (F8), these three errors occur:

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Report-Template.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Report-Template.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Report-Template.aux
```

Comment: You are mixing bibtex and biblatex code. Please see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) about very basic concepts about bibliography in LateX.

Comment: You (most likely) need to run `biber` in between runs of `pdflatex`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number for a description of how this works. (If you pass `backend=bibtex` as an option to `biblatex` then you need to run `bibtex` not `biber`.)

Comment: The template will have a `\useapackage[<some options here>]{biblatex}` call somewhere. You need to replace the option `style=` or the options `citestyle`/`bibstyle` with `style=ieee`. Note that this will give a bibliography emulating IEEE style, it will not give you a bibliography you can use to submit to the IEEE. For submissions you should use the official IEEEE templates, which use `.bst` styles and not `biblatex`. You can read up about the difference between `biblatex` and BibTeX bibliographies at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864

Comment: For full IEEE style you want `style=IEEE` instead of only `citestyle=ieee`. Other than that you need to run Biber, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864

Comment: ok,thx for your answers!  I'm gonna read up on the difference between bibtex and biblatex then.

Comment: Your last edit confirms you are running BibTeX, but you should be running Biber instead. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: guys, it is working! - you were right, I had to run biber.