# What citation package to use

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib, cite-package

As far as I can tell the three major citation packages are:

- `natbib`
- `cite`
- `biblatex`

There already is a discussion on the relation between `natbib` and `biblatex` here: [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) However, the `cite` package is left out, and I'm having a hard time finding anything on this stack exchange about the matter.

The linked question has me wanting to use `biblatex`, however I don't know   if `cite` would be better.

So my question is:

What are the pros and cons of `cite` compared to `natbib` and `biblatex` and are there other packages in the jungle of citation packages? If there are other packages then; when (if ever) should I consider using them?

Comment: use _always_  `biblatex`

Comment: @Herbert would you add that as an answer?

Comment: The `cite` package plays a similar role as `natbib` in the comparison `natbib` vs `biblatex`. (Of course the two packages `cite` and `natbib` have different capabilities, but the same general considerations apply.)

Comment: @moewe Thanks for the info ;-) I'll use biblatex then. Would you add it as an answer instead of as a comment?

Comment: I'll think about writing an answer, but it may take a bit of time.

Comment: @moewe No problem I just like not having "answered in the comments" questions lying around

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of what is said about `natbib` in [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib) also applies to `cite`. They play a similar role and both use the same underlying workflow to produce bibliographies: Compilation with BibTeX and `.bst` files (this is what I called "the BibTeX way of creating bibliographies" [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864)). In fact both packages are mainly concerned with the output of citations and not so much with the bibliography output, which is controlled by the `.bst` files.

The difference between `natbib` and `cite` is 'only' in their specific set of features, while the difference to `biblatex` is conceptional.

`natbib` and `cite` are incompatible and `natbib` emulates some key features of the `cite` package (see p. 1 of [the `natbib` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf)). I haven't actually checked if you can recreate everything that `cite` can do with `natbib`, but I'm fairly confident that you can get quite far.

`natbib` offers many features that `cite` does not have, mainly support for author-year citations (`.bst` file permitting) and new citation commands like `\citep`, `\citet`, ...

There are more BibTeX-based citation packages: [`apacite`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf), [`harvard`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/harvard/harvard.pdf), ... There is also [`jurabib`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/jurabib/docs/english/jbendoc.pdf), but `jurabib` takes the idea of BibTeX bibliographies to the next level and is in some ways much closer to `biblatex`'s approach than to the other packages.

For what it is worth you might not need a package like `cite` or `natbib` at all if you are only after simple numeric citations. LaTeX's built-in `\cite` might already be enough for you. See [What bibliography is used if no package is loaded?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/451287/35864?noredirect=1) and [What is the default bibliography package and backend in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/361645/35864).

---

If you have already decided that you want to use `biblatex` instead of `natbib`, I don't really think you would want to use `cite` instead.

That said, while I am very happy to recommend to use `biblatex` there is at least one area where `biblatex` is clearly inferior to BibTeX-based bibliography solutions: Submissions to publishers and journals as well as preprint services with on-server compilation like the arXiv (see [Biblatex: submitting to a journal](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12175/35864) and [Making the arXiv accept a BibTeX BBL (May 2018)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/429436/35864) as well as many other questions about this topic). Additionally, `biblatex` is still being developed, so there is a risk of changes (some of which might not be fully backwards compatible, take the notorious [Biblatex 3.3 name formatting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/299036/35864)). Most BibTeX-based solutions have been stable for many moons and are therefore usually not very sensitive to version issues.