# Using natbib and thebibliography

Tags: natbib

I'm trying to create a citation like:

> The books (Charles, 1985; Smith, 1989) are great.

by using package `natbib` and

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[(Charles, 1985)]{Charles85}

\bibitem[(Smith, 1989)]{Smith89}

\end{thebibliography}{}
```

But the command `\citep{Charles85,Smith89}` does not seem to work.

Comment: `(<Name>, <Year>)` is not a format `natbib` can parse in the optional argument to `\bibitem`. Drop the parentheses and try `<Name>, <Year>`: `\bibitem[Charles, 1985]{Charles85}`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604

Answer (score 2):

`natbib` needs the author and year information in the optional argument of `\bibitem` to be in a special format so it can be parsed. `natbib.sty` explains the possible formats in a comment

```
 % If author-year citations are selected, \bibitem must have one of the
 %   following forms:
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)Jones, Baker, and Williams]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[Jones et al., 1990]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{Jones
 %       et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\astroncite{Jones et al.}{1990}]{key}...
 %   \bibitem[\protect\citename{Jones et al., }1990]{key}...
 %   \harvarditem[Jones et al.]{Jones, Baker, and Williams}{1990}{key}...
```

The format used in the question

```
\bibitem[(Charles, 1985)]{Charles85}
```

is not among the supported formats. The simplest way to make the information digestible for `natbib` is probably by dropping the parentheses to make it read

```
\bibitem[Charles, 1985]{Charles85}
```

Alternatively, you could use the format that `natbib`'s standard `.bst` files use

```
\bibitem[Charles(1985)]{Charles85}
```

In total

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}


\begin{document}
\citep{Charles85,Smith89}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem[Charles, 1985]{Charles85} Anne Charles: \emph{Title}. 1985

\bibitem[Smith, 1989]{Smith89} Jane Smith: \emph{Another Title}. 1989

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: (Charles, 1985; Smith, 1989)]

---

That said, it is usually more comfortable to use `.bib` files and BibTeX (or `biblatex` and Biber: [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864)) instead of a manual `thebibliography`. Entries can be re-used and re-styled more easily and BibTeX (or Biber) takes care of sorting.

Comment: additionally writing bibliographies (even inside of a bib file) in a manual fashion is a very complicated process compared to how life is with tools like jabreb and the like

Comment: How do you get this setup to number the references?

Comment: @Shaun `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}` instead of `\usepackage{natbib}` should work. Or you fine-tune the output with `\setcitestyle`.

Comment: Thank you, @moewe. I'll try this tomorrow, once I have time.