# A problem with bibliography in Aberdeen OverLeaf dissertation template document

Tags: bibliographies, texniccenter

I use [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-aberdeen-thesis-template/jzrbyqmggygd).  See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700171/39761) of mine for context.

---

The document is quite complex, so I'm not sure what to share here in terms of code.

I have this:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Bergelson} Bergelson, V., Best, A., and Iosevich (2020). A, Sums of Powers in Large Finite Fields: A Mix of Methods \textit{The American Mathematical Monthly} (2021), 128:8, pp. 701-718.
\end{thebibliography}
```

However, when I load it, TeXnicCentre says there is an error.  When I click of the error, the following shows up:

[image]

---

The problem, of course, seems to be in how I have entered the reference.

Comment: `natbib` needs the author and year information in the optional argument of `\bibitem`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479181/42803

Comment: That sorted it, @AndreyL.. Thank you!

Comment: Although that did fix the problem, I don't think this template uses `natbib`. . .