# Not able to include BibTeX from external file in my thesis

Tags: bibliographies, texshop

I want to cite reference in my `introduction` file. Unfortunately, there is confusion which document type I should give. My `main.tex` is already has type. Any solution to manage references in thesis work?

**`main.tex` file:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, openright]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage[margin=1in, left=1in, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

    \input{titlepage}

    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \input{abstract}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Abstract}
    \cleardoublepage

    \input{dedication}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Dedication}
    \cleardoublepage

    \input{declaration}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Declaration}
    \cleardoublepage

    \input{acknowledgements}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}
    \cleardoublepage

%LIST OF FIGURES, LIST OF TABLES
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage

%TABEL OF CONTENT
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty} %this is used to remove page number from table of content page
\cleardoublepage %used to separate the table of content from introduction

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\include{chapters/introduction}

\chapter{Empirical Study on Child Computer Interaction}
\include{chapters/chap06}
\cleardoublepage


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{/Users/pythonbuddha/Documents/Thesis/References.bib}
\section*{References}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}References}
\cleardoublepage

%Appendix starts here

\appendix
\section*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\numberline{}Appendix}
\cleardoublepage
This is the appendix.

\end{document}
```

**ìntroduction.tex`file:**

```
\thispagestyle{plain}

    \vspace{0.9cm}
\section*{Introduction}
    \vspace{0.4cm}
A positive approach for the scratch users are children can brush up their mathematical skills while making small programs. \cite{lewis2012building}
```

Comment: Welsome to TeX SX! Did you run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex->bibtex->(pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604

Comment: Looking at your main file and especially your file `introduction.tex` you just need to get in trouble. All your toc entries are possibly leading to a wrong page. You suddenly have a new `\begin{document}` in the introduction. Manual spacing. Please read an introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: @Johannes_B, `toc` entries are not leading to wrong pages in this case. Unfortunately, I am not able to cite references in my `introduction.tex` file. As Now I removed `\begin{document}` tag in `introduction.tex` file. Do you know any solution to link references in man.tex file which are being used in different chapters in the thesis document?

Comment: @Bernard, as I run `bibtex`cycle as you mentioned, it shows `DONE` message at the end. so, not confusion is how to cite reference!