# Using Different line spacing in the paragraph of lyx

Tags: bibliographies, lyx, line-spacing

I am writing my thesis using Lyx 2.3.3. I have written my bibliography but the output is not looking how I want it to look I have a lot of spacing between lines. Can someone help me get the lines shrunken for the paragraphs please?

This is how it is looking:

[image]

and this is how I want it to look:

[image]

The document spacing is double but I want for the bibiliography would be smaller as it is not looking professional.

Can someone help please?

Comment: More information is really necessary, but since you're using Lyx, you may not be able to tell us what document class is being used.  But perhaps you can tell us how the bibliography items are entered.  The output you show looks like they are entered as separate text paragraphs.  It's more appropriate to identify them by a command such as `\bibitem` within a dedicated bibliography environment.  But again, how that is set up depends on the document class.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I think I managed all i need to do is use the `description`. I never managed to use bibtex or anything so i inputted them manually

Comment: You've identified a mechanism that will keep each entry "together".  It's not what's usually recommended, but it captures the necessary characteristic.  This is worth a self-answer, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Without a real MWE to test, maybe is more complex that this, but ...

1. Select with the mouse the gray box `BibTeX Generated Bibliography` (a blue background should appear).
2. Right-click (a floating menu should be showed).
3. Select `Paragraphs Settings ...`
4. In `Line Spacing` menu, select `Single`
5. Click on `Apply` or `OK`

The `Source Code Pane` (menu View)  then should show like that ...

```
\documentclass[whatever]{whatever}
...
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
...
\begin{document}
 Whatever ....

\begin{singlespace}
\bibliographystyle{whatever} % or simply  
\bibliography{whatever}      % \printbibliography using biblatex
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

The french indentation is a matter of the bibliographic style. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604)  have examples with both bibtex and biblatex producing this format. That is indeed better that use a description environment.