# Bibliography in latex

Tags: bibliographies

First I'm german, so sorry for any mistakes.
I've been on so many websites but not a single one could help me. I'm writing my Bachelor thesis and all I still need is my bibliography.
In a shorter form:

```
\bibliographystyle[unsrt] 
\usepackage[backend= biber, style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{lit.bib}
\begin{document}
```

...

```
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

So thats basically what I wrote. I created a file named lit.bib in the correct form. If I wanna see the PDF version, I don't get an error. It doesn't print the bib at all.
No idea what I'm doing wrong. I'd be vey thankful for any help!

Lisa :)

Comment: If references are not cited in the text, you have to add `\nocite{*}`in the preamble. Needless to add `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`. This is not biblatex syntax, and it's simpler to replace it with the biblatex option `[sorting=none]`. Last: did you run the normal cycle: `(pdf)latex -> biber -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?.

Comment: `\bibliographystyle[unsrt]` is wrong syntax and `\bibliographystyle` should not be used with `biblatex` anyway. With the document as shown you need to run Biber on your document at least as follows: LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where LaTeX can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. If you are using an editor, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: Please see in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) a quick introduction to the three options to make a bibliography in LaTeX. I guess from you wrong code that you are trying to use the third option (biblatex) but  you are mixing (wrongly) that options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I found my mistake beside the mixed syntax. I needed to change the TexMaker Configuration from bibtex to biber.