# How to make Bibliography in style

Tags: bibliographies

[image: bibliography]

I have read and watch some tutorial "how to make bibliography" like the picture. But, I can't understand how to make it. please give me with some codes (tex and bib files) which I can edit for my purposes.

Comment: Examples like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604)?

Comment: @Fran, yeah... but I really dont understand it. Can you help me?

Comment: In the "bibtex" section of the answer, save the `References.bib` example  and the next code  (that is a complete LaTeX file) as `MyDocument.tex` in the same directory. Then, in  the system prompt in this directory, run `pdflatex MyDocument.tex` and after that, `bibtex MyDocument` and again `pdflatex MyDocument.tex` two times more. At the end, you should have a `MyDocument.pdf`  in the same directory (of course, with the reference as showed the picture of the answer).

Comment: @Fran, Package biblatex Error: File 'tesdapus.bbl' not created by biblatex. that the messages

Comment: The instructions of the  above comment cannot produce a biblatex error nor that file name. If I tell you exactly how to do with bibtex, but you do something else involving biblatex  in some way  (that only  you know)   ... how do you think I can help?

Comment: @Fran I dont know. I'm very dont understand with this. I have save a file like `References.bib`, the name is `dapusapa`. And my document name is `tesdapus.tex`. And I run `tesdapus.tex`, and that the message

Comment: It *seems* that you are trying the "biblatex approach" but running `bibtex`, but I don't know what the hell you have wrote in `tesdapus.tex`and `dasudapa.bib`, so we are in a non sense dialog.  Last suggestion:  (1) Try to compile my examples using bibtex *or* biblatex **exactly** as explained (2) If this works, construct from that examples your own document with *one* of these methods. (3) In case of error,  reduce your document to a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem and **edit your question** to show us that code.

Comment: @Fran, [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134180/how-do-i-add-citations-at-the-end-of-the-document-as-done-here/134182#134182) work. But if I compile with my full project, it is not working. I hope can send you my full project.

Comment: thankyou @Fran,  I dont know what to say. First is not working, but when I Copy all my code project and make new project, it's work. Do you know what happen?

Comment: @Fran, I have new [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520757/change-bibliography-format-in-latx-book)