# Change bibliography format in LaTeX book

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

[image]

How to change the format of bibliography, like the screenshot (into that square position, font 14, and the word "Bibliography" become "DAFTAR PUSTAKA". And how to set the horizontal space in the line 2 become 1 cm.

This is my main.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{book}
  \usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
  \addbibresource{references.bib}
  \begin{document}
  Someone have found a simple solution  \parencite{Gill}.

  Someone has found a simple solution  \citep[see page 47]{Gill}.

  A simple solution has been found by \citeauthor{Gill} in \citeyear{Gill}.
  \printbibliography

  \end{document}
```

and this is file `references.bib`

```
@ARTICLE{Gill,
   author    = "A. E. Gill",
   title     = "Some Simple Solutions for Heat-Induced Tropical Circulation",
   journal   = "Quart. J. R. Met. Soc.",
   volume    = 106,
   year      = 1980,
   pages     = "447-462",
}
```

Comment: The bibliography heading is typeset as a normal `\chapter*`. Do you want to change the appearance of all chapter headers or only of the bibliography? You can change the title of the bibliography with `\printbibliography[title={Lorem Ipsum}]` if your language is not supported out of the box by `biblatex`.

Comment: For the horizontal space try `\setlength{\bibhang}{1cm}`.

Comment: @moewe, oke , that's work. But how to set the position and the font?