# Lyx: Citation for 2 authors separated by comma doesn't leave space

Tags: bibliographies, citing, lyx, punctuation

I'm a new user of Lyx and I am writing a thesis by using the default bibliography (i.e. I use the "class" bibliography instead of standard/chapter, etc.).

In the bibliography, as a key I need to put 2 authors, for example: XXX, YYY (2010) and then cite it. For example: "In XXX, YYY (2010) the authors argue that..."

Unfortunately, when I cite it the resulting text is: "In XXX,YYY (2010) the authors argue that..." without any space after the comma. Also, if I click on the reference it seems like Lyx is splitting the reference into 2 references: XXX and YYY (2010) using the comma as the splitter.

I wanted to ask if someone knows how to leave the space after the comma and obtain: "In XXX, YYY (2010) the authors argue that..."

Thanks a lot to whoever can help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing the problem?

Comment: XXX, YYY (2010) should be the **label** ot the bibitem, not the key, that should be a single unique word as `xxx10`, so that the code produce must be `In \cite{foo} the authors argue that ... `  and later   `\bibitem[XXX, YYY (2010)]{foo} ...`

Comment: BTW, this is the worst approach to make a bibliography.  LyX suport also bibtex\bilatex but you should know first how these approaches works  in LaTeX (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604), for instance)  to understand what to do in Document > Settings > bibliography.