# Bib file can not be processed

Tags: bibtex, texmaker, auxiliary-files

Here is my whole bib file `Refs.bib`

```
@book{Shalev,
author = {Shalev-Shwartz, Shai and Ben-David, Shai},
title={Understanding Machine Learning},
year={2014},
publisher ={Cambridge University Press, NY},
}
```

I am trying to run BibTex on it. 
The Texmaker outputs an error:

```
"I couldn't open file name `Refs.aux'
Process exited normally"
```

The TexWorks does not output anything: it just hangs indefinitely.

What is going on?

Comment: You need to run BibTeX on your main `.tex` file and not on the `.bib` file. You can only run BibTeX after you have successfully run LaTeX on your main `.tex` file. This means you compile your main `.tex` file with LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: Quick start: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134180/how-do-i-add-citations-at-the-end-of-the-document-as-done-here

Comment: Yes, this particular issue is resolved. Thank you.