# How to combine given bib file with a given cls file?

Tags: templates

I am working on a thesis using MikTex.

I was given a cls file and a bib file.

My question is how do we combine these?

Comment: You don't combine the two files. They do completely different things. A `.bib` file contains references that you can cite and send to the bibliography (if your document contains the right setup for that). A `.cls` files is defines the document class, i.e. the overall layout of your document, it is loaded with `\documentclass` (which is usually the first or at least one of the first lines) in your document.

Comment: Did whoever gave you those files also give you a README or some documentation (or some help in person)? Or at least an example `.tex` file that describes how one should use the `.bib` and `.cls` file? Since we don't know what the files you have look like we can't give more specific help and can only explain things in very general terms.

Comment: I have previously used LaTex, but I am new to the bib file used for the bibliography.Maybe I did not phrase my issue appropriately. I want to add this bib file to my document. How do I do that?

Comment: Thank you @moewe

Comment: There are broadly two methods to using `.bib` files: Classical BibTeX or `biblatex`. (They are explained along with the manual `thebibliography` approach in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134180/35864 and probably also in most good LaTeX tutorials.) With BibTeX you can load additional packages like `cite`, `natbib`, ... to extend (the initially very basic) functionality. `biblatex` is more monolithic and is not used together with additional packages (it can do a lot out of the box). If you have a specific template, chances are it already has code set up for one of the two methods.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix the problem. Originally I had a set section called `thebibliography`.

I thought I needed to modify the `.cls` file to include the .bib file in that particular section, but I was wrong.

What I have done to solve the issue is just comment out that section completely and I added the following

```
\bibliography{mybib} 
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
```

Thank you @moewe for your assistance.