# Bibliography not showing up, even when citing

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am unable to get my bibliography to show up in my LaTeX document when using bibtex. I have already debugged the .bib file, have cited papers so I shouldn't need a \nocite*{} (I think), and I'm not receiving any errors during compilation. Any time I do cite, it shows as a [?]. How can I fix this?

Citation in paper:

```
... commercial or research purposes \cite{FAA-Aerospace-Forecast}.
```

What is in the bibtex:

```
@misc{FAA-Aerospace-Forecast,
    author = {{Federal Aviation Administration (FAA)}},
    title = {{FAA Aerospace Forecast -- Fiscal Years 2019--2039}},
    howpublished = {Online: https://www.faa.gov/data{\_}research/aviation/aerospace{\_}forecasts/media/FY2019-39{\_}FAA{\_}Aerospace{\_}Forecast.pdf },
    year = {2019},
    note = {TC19-0002},
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure you (or your editor) actually run BibTeX. Citations will only resolve correctly if you run the cycle LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX (without errors! here "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX, e.g. pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...) https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains brilliantly what BibTeX is and why you need to run it.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question but for URLs you get usually much better results if you use the `\url` command (for which you need to load the `url` or `hyperref` package) and don't escape special chars, so try `howpublished = {Online: \url{https://www.faa.gov/data_research/aviation/aerospace_forecasts/media/FY2019-39_FAA_Aerospace_Forecast.pdf}},` instead of *`howpublished = {Online: https://www.faa.gov/data{\_}research/aviation/aerospace{\_}forecasts/media/FY2019-39{\_}FAA{\_}Aerospace{\_}Forecast.pdf },`.

Comment: Is the space after the url (after .pdf) intentional? This will not solve the issue, but I just wanted to point your attention to it.

Comment: @moewe  Thank you for your help. However, I am now getting an error telling me that it does not create the .aux file needed. I ran pdfLatex, then bibtex, then pdfLatex again twice, but to no avail. Do you have any advice?

Comment: BTW,  alternatively, you can also construct your MWE starting from the compilable examples of this site, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134180/how-do-i-add-citations-at-the-end-of-the-document-as-done-here/134182), changing as needed to reproduce the error.

Comment: The first LaTeX run should generate an `.aux` file if it runs without error. So the first thing to check is if you actually ran LaTeX without errors. If BibTeX complains it can't find the `.aux` file but you ran LaTeX successfully, there are broadly at least two sources of errors: (1) The `.aux` file is gone/somewhere BibTeX doesn't expect it. Some editors have a "build folder" feature that hides temporary files in a subdirectory, some editors clean up temporary files after you. Make sure the `.aux` file is in the same directory as your main `.tex` file....

Comment: ...  (2) BibTeX needs to run on the correct file name. Assuming your document is called `mydoc.tex` run `bibtex mydoc` or `bibtex mydoc.aux`. You do *not* run BibTeX on your `.bib` file. Unfortunately, we can only help you with this issue if you can share some more details with us: How do you run LaTeX and BibTeX? What is the name of your main `.tex` file? What was the exact BibTeX error message? What does your folder structure look like after a successful LaTeX run? Which editor do you use? What are your editor's compilation settings?

Comment: Thank you, I was running BibTeX on my .bib file and didn't realize I needed to run it on my .aux file. Thank you again