# My PDF does not appear after adding bibliography to Beamer file

Tags: beamer, biblatex, compiling, biber

I want to add a bibliography to my Beamer file. After reading up a bit, I managed to make the compilation work but my PDF does not appear. Thank you for any help.

My code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,t,handout]{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[francais]{babel}
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
        \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{time}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{Biblio.bib}
\begin{document}
\section{Références}
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Référence}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
            \end{document}
```

---

Je vous ajoute mon fichier .bib

```
@misc{noauthor_comparing_nodate,
    title = {Comparing scores {\textbar} {Index} {\textbar} 2015 {\textbar} {Gender} {Equality} {Index} {\textbar} {European} {Institute} for {Gender} {Equality}},
    url = {https://eige.europa.eu/gender-equality-index/2015/compare-countries/index/bar},
    urldate = {2020-06-26},
    file = {Comparing scores | Index | 2015 | Gender Equality Index | European Institute for Gender Equality:C\:\\Users\\user\\Zotero\\storage\\BQ7X6W98\\bar.html:text/html}
}
@article{gautier2000droits,
  title={Les droits reproductifs, une nouvelle génération de droits?},
  author={Gautier, Arlette},
  journal={AUTREPART-BONDY PARIS-},
  number={15},
  pages={167--180},
  year={2000}
}
@misc{noauthor_definition_nodate,
    title = {Définition : {Droit} civil},
    url = {http://www.toupie.org/Dictionnaire/Droit_civil.htm},
    urldate = {2020-06-26},
    file = {Définition \: Droit civil:C\:\\Users\\user\\Zotero\\storage\\8BR2VQT9\\Droit_civil.html:text/html}
}

@misc{noauthor_droits_nodate,
    title = {Droits politiques},
    url = {https://hls-dhs-dss.ch/articles/010368/2014-08-06/},
    abstract = {Les droits politiques (ou droits démocratiques) permettent aux citoyens d'influer sur la formation de la volonté politique. Ils sont l'expression de l'autogestion du peuple. Ce peuple souverain grâce au droit de vote ne doit pas être confondu avec celui qui est soumis aux lois. Il se limite en principe aux membres adultes d'un Etat, qui y possèdent généralement leur domicile. Plus rarement, le droit de vote peut être reconnu aux étrangers. Les droits politiques sont idéologiquement dérivés des principes de la liberté et de l'égalité individuelles. La liberté ne signifie pas seulement l'autonomie privée, mais aussi l'autodétermination. Du point de vue du droit public, les droits politiques comprennent, outre des droits individuels, l'exercice d'une des fonctions organiques de l'Etat. C'est pourquoi le vote est obligatoire dans certains pays.},
    language = {fr},
    urldate = {2020-06-26},
    journal = {hls-dhs-dss.ch},
    file = {Snapshot:C\:\\Users\\user\\Zotero\\storage\\B7DFEUAQ\\2014-08-06.html:text/html}
}
@article{familialeoui,
  title={OUI AU CHOIX, NON AU HASARD:  PLANIFICATION FAMILIALE et DROITS DE LA PERSONNE, },
  author={UNFPA},
date={2012}
}
```

Après compilation le résultat suivant s'affiche:
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.6500 64-bit) The top-level auxiliary file: SR.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file SR.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file SR.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file SR.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: Bienvenue au site. The language of the site is English however. Have you run `biber` and compiled again? Does the the log or the console show any errors that could help us?

Comment: @AlanMunn: Why can't we use Latin? It is as international as (international)English… ;o)

Comment: @Bernard Even the church has given up on Latin and [Nuntii Latini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuntii_Latini) stopped broadcasting, so it seems unlikely to catch on here. :)

Comment: There's Mema Interretialia, tho: https://interretialia.tumblr.com/ TeX in Latin would be really interesting, but as useless.

Comment: You may want to visit https://texnique.fr/osqa/ where you will find Beamer experts...

Comment: Make sure you run Biber on your document. A typical full compilation sequence for a document with `biblatex` bibliography would be LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" can be your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for a great explanation of what Biber does. If you are using an editor that run LaTeX and other programs for you, you may have to tell it explicitly to use Biber and not BibTeX, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864.

Comment: If you ran LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX and still don't get any bibliography output, open the `.blg` file (which despite what Windows may say, is a normal text file) and show its contents.

Comment: You are using `bibtex` not `biber`, but you must use `biber` to use `biblatex` for bibliographies. See the second link that @moewe posted: [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no fatal problems with your code and you don't give any clue to guess why you cannot see the pdf, but most probably you have not compiled correctly the presentation, or there are some problems with `Droit.bib`, so:

How to test:

1. Make a new directory, said   `whatever`
2. Copy your code as `MyDocument.tex` in that directory
3. Edit `MyDocument.tex` and replace `\addbibresource{Droit.bib}` by `\addbibresource{References.bib}`
4. Go to [How do I add "citations" at the end of the document as done here?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134180/how-do-i-add-citations-at-the-end-of-the-document-as-done-here) and copy the example `References.bib` and save it with that name in your new directory.
5. Open the terminal/command prompt, move with `cd` to  `whatever` directory and follow the four compilation steps explained in the link, i.e, after run    `pdflatex MyDocument.tex`, run `biber MyDocument` and then the first step again, two times.
6. Now, it should be a `MyDocument.pdf` in `whatever`, like this:

[image: mwe]

Otherwise, remove any auxiliary file created in your previous attempt (i.e, all files of `whatever` except `MyDocument.tex` and `References.bib`) and tray again, but now pay attention to the messages in the commands prompt and in  `MyDocuemnt.log`. The end of that messages are usually a clue of what are you doing wrongly, but if that messages is like Klingon jargon for you, ask here, but posting that messages. Only "This does not work" do not help.

Comment: bonjour, merci pour les éléments de réponses. je vous envoie le bout de code de mon document .bib.

Comment: @MatièreNoire In the edit of your question  you show that you are trying to use bibtex, but your code is for biblatex with **biber**. The link of my answer explain the difference. You can use or the other, but without mixing them!