# Spaces in Latex bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I would like to reference papers in the bibliography by the names of the authors rather than the number. How do I doo this if there are two authors, and I want to cite as [Author A and Author B, year]?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us more how you build the formatted bibliography. E.g., do you build it entirely by hand, or with the help of a software tool such as BibTeX? Do you load any packages that manage the appearance of citation call-outs? Please be specific.

Comment: Use the authoryear style of biblatex. See [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134180/how-do-i-add-citations-at-the-end-of-the-document-as-done-here).

Comment: If you are using BibTeX (with `\bibliographystyle`), then you need to pick a bibliography style that is capable of producing author-year citation data and you need a LaTeX package that produces author-year citations. In the BibTeX world one of the most commonly used packages for this is `natbib` which comes with a collection of bibliography styles that support author-year citations. (There are other packages: `apacite` for APA style, 6th ed., citations comes to mind.) If you are using `biblatex` a switch should be as easy as saying `style=authoryear`.