# How to hide the references when using natbib package in Latex

Tags: natbib

I have a .bib file (bibliografia.bib) used to cite authors but I don't want to print the references.
My latex document is structured as follows:

```
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}


\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}

\end{document}
```

How can I remove the printed references?

Thanks in advance!

**My attempt**

This worked for me

```
 \usepackage[round]{natbib}
 \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
 \begin{document}
 
\newsavebox\mytempbib
\savebox\mytempbib{\parbox{\textwidth}{\bibliography{bibliografia.bib}}}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: open the pdf file and delete the pages that contain the formatted bibliography?

Comment: @Mico Is there a way to generate pdf's from Latex without the printed references?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: @CelineHarumi You can use the `atbegshi` package to discard (entire) pages from the PDF file.  Load `\usepackage{atbegshi}`, then do `\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}` before the page(s) you want discarded.  In the next LaTeX release this function will be built into the kernel, so you can do (without packages) `\AddToHook{shipout/before}{\DiscardShipoutBox}`.

Comment: The simplest: use `biblatex` with natbib compatibility enabled as showed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) and remove (or comment)  the command  `\printbibliography`.