# Capitalization in bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, capitalization

I would like entries in the bibliography to appear as typed in bibtex, specifically with capitalization when it occurs. But bibtex does not capitalize letters unless the are wrapped in an extra set of braces in the bib file. Apparently this is an intended feature (a terrible feature in my opinion). I do not want to edit the bib file manually since there are hundreds of entries and searching for where the extra braces are needed is tiring. It seems most bibtex users are aware of this; there have been many questions like this one on stack exchange - but the answers all involve manually editing the bib-file.

Is there really automatic solution - no command I can put in the tex file like `\bibliographycaptialization=true`, or changing the `\bibliographystyle`?
If not, then how can I make a request to latex or miktex designers for something like this?

Comment: That depend on  the  bibliographic style. You can either change the bibtex style (even one customized, although is not  a very simple task ...) or use biblatex, that by default maintain capitalization as is. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) you have an example comparing  the output of the same capitalized  reference with bibtex and bilatex.

Comment: BTW,  some styles without using sentence case titles are  `vancouver`, `ACM-Reference-Format`,  `UNAMThesis`, `ajae` .... and in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file) one of the answer  include how modify a .bst file to avoid changes of the title.