# Why I cannot get a APA result from Biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, overleaf

The content like that, when I copy it to overleaf ,it didn't get a suitable result

```
\begin{document}
    @software{dias2019fuzzy,
      author       = {Madson Luiz Dantas Dias},
      title        = {fuzzy-c-means: An implementation of Fuzzy $C$-means clustering algorithm.},
      month        = may,
      year         = 2019,
      publisher    = {Zenodo},
      doi          = {10.5281/zenodo.3066222},
      url          = {https://git.io/fuzzy-c-means}
    }
\end{document}
```

the result like that, how to solve this problem?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. I suggest that you add more details to your question, such as providing a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: That website definitely does not use real BibTeX to format the output. It uses some JavaScript. It appears that has a hard-coded list of entry types it accepts (https://github.com/enric1994/bibtexonline/blob/6019bff775951db99e40462af89fd41c2887559f/js/BibTex.js#L864-L879) everything else is ignored. `@software` is not on the list.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thanks for your reply, my question is focusing on how to convert the bibtex to other format, and example just said above

Comment: You can open an issue at https://github.com/enric1994/bibtexonline/issues and ask for support for more entry types or at least more graceful behaviour if the entry type is not known. (Like 'fall back to `@misc`', which is what most BibTeX styles do.)

Comment: @moewe I really appreciate your help. the problem is how can I convert it to another format, like APA or MLA...

Comment: That depends on how you want to do it. That webpage uses JavaScript to format a hard-coded list of entry types via a hard-coded scheme into text. If you use `.bib` files with LaTeX you would usually have them parsed and interpreted by BibTeX, which produces output according to your selected style (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134180/35864 and https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-12). But there are several solutions out there (like this webpage) that try to make `.bib` entries usable without BibTeX: Some a better, some are worse

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Unfortunately your edit has made the question completely unclear. This has nothing to do with Overleaf or even `biblatex` as far as I can tell. If you are writing a document on Overleaf then you can use regular methods to produce APA citations and bibliography.  If that’s not what you are doing you need to explain much more clearly what it is you want.

Comment: The Q&A https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134180/35864 that I linked in my comment above has short examples explaining the several methods to produce citations and bibliographies with `.bib` files that there are in LaTeX. Usually this will go via a `.bib` file and dedicated commands in your document. You will not paste the entry into your document directly. If you are working with Overleaf, they have help pages explaining these things rather nicely: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Using_bibliographies_on_Overleaf