# How to manage and display ref from .bib file

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying the ACM conference template ... they have a separate .bib file, which I have never used.

First on Google Scholar I am researching the paper. Then open ref style-->click on bibTex-->
then copying this

```
@article{maskin1999nash,
title={Nash equilibrium and welfare optimality},
author={Maskin, Eric},
journal={The Review of Economic Studies},
volume={66},
number={1},
pages={23--38},
year={1999},
publisher={Wiley-Blackwell} }
```

and pasted in my .bib file (sample-bibliography.bib). Then in the main file I am using `\bibliography{sample-bibliography}` to print a reference in the reference section, but the problem is it is not printing the reference ...

Comment: The ACM conference template that I could  find via a quick Google search has a BibTeX-based bibliography and does not use `biblatex`. Furthermore, the symptoms you are describing in the comments ([?] appearing) suggest you are using a BibTeX-based method and not `biblatex`, so I retagged your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you have never used a .bib file, my suggestion is to start with this [quick introduction](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) about managing cites and references in LaTeX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only cited works in a `.bib` file are printed in the bibliography. So you need to either cite the work (using `\cite{maskin1999nash}` for an in-text citation or `\nocite{maskin1999nash}` to force the work in the reference work even though there's no in-text citation).

Of course, you don't indicate whether you've run BibTeX to generate the `.bbl` file which is what's actually responsible for producing a bibliography. You need to run BibTeX *after* a LaTeX run that had a version of your LaTeX file, and then re-run LaTeX to actually get the biblography.

Comment: \cite{maskin1999nash} will be used for intext citation .. in my case i want to print references at end of paper in bibliography section .. in my template the no reference is showing in reference section it is blanked

Comment: Yes, it is used for intext citation, but the bibliography at the end of your paper will, by default, only list entries that were in fact cited. Sources that are in your .bib file but are not cited will be omitted from your bibliography.

Comment: got it .. now i did that still reference are not there

Comment: @article{b1,
  title={Nash equilibrium and welfare optimality},
  author={Maskin, Eric},
  year={2019}     and then cite as \cite{b1}
}

Comment: i dont know where i am making mistake .. i tried in anothe rproject and in that it only print in-text like this [?]

Comment: o i came to know its due to bibliography style .. when i am using ACM its is printing [?] on plain style it works fine . .. what should i do so it can work on ACM style too