# How do I correctly add bibtex to my project?

Tags: biblatex

So I am writing my first article with Latex and I've got 20 pages so far. I did copy all my references so I could just input them at the end. While starting inserting my references, I found out that there is a way to just copy some bibtex reference and generate a customized reference page. I started reading some guides and following some tutorials but i always ended up having "no reference to citation". I don't know if I missed something out in my project or just horribly failed at some point but I just try to describe my project to you:

I have every chapter split into different files sorted into different folders. I have folder "chapter_1" - "chapter_6". Inside every folder are .tex files and pictures. My first page and table of contents are in the same directory as the main.tex.

So first of I created a file called "reference.bib" and put 1 reference inside to test this out. I went into my main.tex and added

```
\usepackage[backend=biber]{bibtex}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}
```

to my preamble. Then I went to the point i want the reference page to be printed and inserted a `\printbibliography{reference.bib}`. Lastly I went to the part I wanted to cite and put a `\cite{1234}` (the corresponding number) in the text. Compiling always gave me no references and errors. I did it the exact same way most other did this and I don't know what to do at this point.

If the description is not detailed enough just let me know, i'd go ahead and share most of the code I wrote.

Comment: Did you run Biber on your document? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 explains why you need to run Biber. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 explains how you can make your editor run Biber.

Comment: \usepackage[backend=biber]{`biblatex`}

Comment: Oh yeah right, the package is called **`biblatex`**, not `bibtex`. So `\usepackage[backend=biber]{bibtex}` should be `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`. (Same for the title: It should be `biblatex` and not bibtex.)

Comment: Thanks for correcting, this was the issue in combination with using wrong parameters and commands. I did try and tweak a little with it but i sadly can't get it to be the APA style my teacher wants me to use.. Is there a way to tweak so the cite state the name + year in square brackets and in the bibliography it starts with [name+year], then the name and everythin but in the second line it gives me an indent?

Comment: you get apa style with biblatex by using `\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex}`. And better use `biber` instead of `bibtex` for the processing.

Comment: @koleygr Do you want to type up a quick answer? (It might be good to also mention having to run Biber even though the only problem visible in the question is the typo.)

Comment: Done @moewe ... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SX!@marcopasta

There are at least 3 ways to use bibliography in LaTeX related software:

1. Use **BibTeX**:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{natbib}
   \begin{document}
    This is a citation~\citep{SomeOne}

    This is a citation about \citet{SomeOther} that \ldots

   \bibliographystyle{apalike}
   \bibliography{MyBibFile}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Use **biblatex** (actually `biber`):

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage[style=apa,natbib=true]{biblatex} 
   \addbibresource{MyBibFile.bib} 
   \begin{document} 

   This is a citation~\citep{SomeOne}

   This is a citation about \citet{SomeOther} that \ldots

   \printbibliography
   \end{document}
   ```
3. **Manually added bibliography**

The `\begin{bibliography}` and `\end{bibliography}` where you are placing `\bibitem`s manually

In your question you just combined the two first methods in a wrong way (they are not combine-able anyway)

Comment: Maybe you could make it clearer that most likely `\usepackage[backend=biber]{bibtex}` is just a typo for `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`.

Comment: Some more examples for the three methods can also be found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134180/35864. It is worth keeping in mind that with `biblatex` one needs to run Biber instead of BibTeX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 can help with the necessary configurations for people's editors).