# \printbibliography does to show anything

Tags: biblatex

I have a following problem. I would like to add list of references on the last frame.
My code:

```latex
\documentclass[]{beamer}
% Class options include: notes, notesonly, handout, trans,
%                        hidesubsections, shadesubsections,
%                        inrow, blue, red, grey, brown

% Theme for beamer presentation.
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} 
% Other themes include: beamerthemebars, beamerthemelined, 
%                       beamerthemetree, beamerthemetreebars  

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=none]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}


\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}                         %bibliography database

\begin{document}

\section[Outline]{}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Name}   % Insert frame title between curly braces

  \begin{itemize}
    \item blabla \cite{ranson2014crime} 
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \printbibliography[title=References]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Bibliography is in a file `Bibliography.bib`. I am able to cite, but no full bibliography is listed at the end:

[image]

How can I fix it please?

Comment: you need to run biber once.

Comment: Unrelated, but lose `\bibliography{Bibliography.bib}` and keep `\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}`, which is the proper way to load datasets when using `biblatex`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for your reply. Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: search for "run biber" on this site. There are lots of answers.

Comment: [Some simple examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) to quickly understand how to make the bibliography with LaTeX.