# Custom bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibliographystyle, custom-bib

I tried to create a custom bibliography style using the cmd panel and
`latex makebst`. I watched a [YouTube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=05yVud1EHjw) and read a lot of blog entries (for example [this](https://www.blopig.com/blog/2013/02/how-to-make-a-custom-latex-bibliography-style/) and [this](http://gabrielelanaro.github.io/blog/2014/12/01/latex-bibliography-in-5-minutes.html)) and all had the same procedure. So i did the same. But if I use my bib style i get the message, that the Citations had not be defined though i created a *sources.bib* file and linked it with `\bibliography{sources}` (sometimes in the preambel, sometimes in the document/ between \begin{document} and \end{} and even under \end{}) and in the resulting pdf question marks pop up in the places where it use `\cite{}`. The *sources.bib* file worked with BibLatex and BibTex (where i used `\autocite{}` but that is not defined for the custom package).

I used the `\usepackage{natbib}` package as it was shown in the internet but that does not make any difference. I even tried it without any packages (no natbib, no Bibtex, nothing else) which gives me exactly the same result.

My procedure was:

Open cmd panel, type `latex makebst`, answering all the questions, copying the .bst file in the folder of the document i want to create, defining `\bibliographystyle{first_try}`, where first_try is the name I gave my .bst file and linking my sources with `\bibliography{sources}`.

**So what have i forgotten?**

Example code:

```
\documentclass[]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{packets} %file where i load all packages but none of them are relevant or i insert  \usepackage{natbib} there

\author{-------}
\title{+++++++}
\date{October 2022}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
I want to cite here \cite{hobbit:original}
\bibliography{sources}
\bibliographystyle{first_try}

\tableofcontents
\include{first chapter}
\include{second chapter}

%\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title={References}] % only for BibLatex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what "no Bibtex" means. E.g., are you not running BibTeX at all?

Comment: Are you able to compile this with a standard bibliographic  style  with like `plain`? If not, [start with this basic examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) and only if you are able to make a PDF with the Bibtex examples, try to change the style of theses examples (not with your text nor your references) with your custom style.

Comment: @fran yes it works with the standard things

Comment: @Mico i do not use any packages like BibLatex or similar at all. I tried it, as i said, with natbib, but that changed nothing.