# Referene in latex without biber

Tags: tex-core

I am trying to retype books in latex but this book have references. I don't have a biber file of all the references in the book. Is there a way to just copy and paste the references from the book and format them right. I couldn't find anything on the internet can anyone help me?

Comment: Assuming you want to retype *everything* exactly as it is in the book, you'd probably not go for a `.bib` file and any of LaTeX's bibliography solutions at all. You'd probably just retype everything by hand each time. Depending on how exactly references are formatted in the source code you might get away with generating your bibliography with `thebibliography` in which case you can use `\cite`, but that will only work if the work you are copying has a citation style that is compatible with `thebibliography` (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134180/35864 for how that would look).

Answer (score 0):

- Much time and effort can be saved by automatically generating BibTeX files through bulk export of
  multiple references either direct from databases or from reference management software. This
  automatic process may cause some issues and require you to tidy up the BibTeX files. Below are
  some suggestions to help with this:
- LaTeX special characters (e.g. $, %, &, ,) present in a BibTeX file can create problems
  during typesetting. To avoid this, all these characters should be prefixed with the ‘\’
  character. Use a text editor such as Notepad or TeXworks to Find and Replace e.g. replace
  $ with $
- The BibTeX file is likely to contain extra fields of information not required for the actual
  reference. This information may pull through into the reference e.g. Notes field. It is
  recommended to remove this information from the BibTeX file
- Retaining capitalization. Some bibliography styles strip out capitalization in fields such as the
  title field; this can be a problem if you want to preserve e.g. acronyms. To preserve
  capitalization, edit the BibTeX file and enclose the specific text (whole not partial words) in curly brackets:
- e.g. title={Study of incompressible {MHD} flow in a circular pipe with transverse magnetic
  field using a spectral/finite element solver},

Comment: TL;DR: Export the references from a database and use BibTeX after all.