# How to use references in latex with standard templates for thesis?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing

I am a newbie to latex. I was trying to use references in latex.
I was attempting to have the author's name and the year of publication appear in my literature section in place of reference numbers (for example, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s0j1.png) --> XYZ1 (2007)). Additionally, I don't want square brackets in the reference section (ex. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s0j1.png) --> 1.).
I am trying but am unable to sort this issue.
I have attached the file[image: output pdf with code]

Comment: Don't show screen shots. Provide an MWE that we can compile that shows your problem and how you tried to fix it.show

Comment: Hi @A S - by the looks of your screenshot you’re using TeXWorks, which comes with MikTeX. Correct? Anyway, you didn’t specific the way your document should handle references. So it is rendered using default instructions for BibTeX to handle references. You may consider using the `apa` style provided by the package `biblatex` and `biber`. That combination does what you are looking for.

Comment: You are using the `plain` bibtex style but there are many others styles, and more options than bibtex. Take your time to [understand the basics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134180/how-do-i-add-citations-at-the-end-of-the-document-as-done-here).