# Why is my bibliography not showing?

Tags: bibliographies

Why is my bibliography not working?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESeov.png)

Apparently the code is correct, but my references are not appearing, could someone help me?

[image]

Reference code :
[image]

Include reference on main file:
[image]

Code new references:
[image]

Comment: `\nocite{*}` possibly before `\printbibliography` command. But please, always add a MWE (minimal working example) instead of posting images. Welcome!

The suggested command is a way to add the bibliography without citation commands, the most common and for me a better way (in most cases) is to `\cite` each reference at the place that you have used it

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Unfortunately, an image of a part of a bib file is not enough for anyone to know what's wrong with your code. You should edit your question to add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201628), that is, a short example of code that can directly be compiled and that reproduces the problem.

Comment: In addition to previous comments, you might want to see [how to write a working example with bibliography](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/140456)

Comment: Check first that you are able to compile [these sample examples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) then compare what you are doing. If you cannot find what is wrong in your code or workflow, make the MWEB linked by the above comment and post the code in plain text marked as code, not in screenshots.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry for my question.
Sorry guys I don't program in this language and I'm using a model provided by the university.

Comment: I didn't use \cite in the script, now it worked, how would I load all the references, even those without citations?