# Merging different citation systems (Copernicus)

Tags: biblatex, citing

I want to publish a paper, but the paper in their LaTeX mask uses a completely different citation system than I do.

The mask of the paper is: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/copernicus-publications-manuscript-preparation-template-for-latex-submissions/xmgtnrsvtptt

using the citation system:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{}

\bibitem[AUTHOR(YEAR)]{LABEL1}
REFERENCE 1

\bibitem[AUTHOR(YEAR)]{LABEL2}
REFERENCE 2

\end{thebibliography}

However, I have always used the system:

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{literature}
\printbibliography
```

and my bibliography looks like this:

```
@article{insert,
  title={Temperature and precipitation effects on the isotopic composition of global precipitation reveal long-term climate dynamics},
  author={Vystavna, Y and Matiatos, I and Wassenaar, LI},
  journal={Scientific Reports},
  volume={11},
  number={1},
  pages={1--9},
  year={2021},
  publisher={Nature Publishing Group}
}
```

However, Copernicus offers the following:

[image]

But when I activate this everything crashes and I can't even see the errors!

Comment: The suggestion in those comments is obviously completely wrong.

Comment: you mean the commends from copernicus?

Comment: Yes: `\bibliographystyle` should not be used with `biblatex` and `\printbibliography` is a `biblatex` command. Unless the `copernicus` package does something strange.

Comment: Thank you so much I am a bit frustrated as the work is almost done but I can't manage the citations :)

Comment: Remove the `thebibliography` environment, put `\bibliographystyle{copernicus}` and `\bibliography{mybibfile}` where you want the bibliography to appear. Locally you will need to [follow this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/106162) and run latex and bibtex a few times, on Overleaf bibtex should run automatically.  This should either work or give a clear error, if something is crashing please confirm which editor you're using.

Comment: thank you very much that helped that half of the quotes are printed i will check again what is with the other half :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `copernicus` class uses a `natbib`-based citation/bibliography setup. (Weirdly though v10.1.4 [2022/12/05] of the class checks if the `natbib` package is available, loads it if it is available and continues with a warning if it isn't. This could lead to very inconsistent results on different systems without a helpful error message.)

This means it is incompatible with `biblatex` and its `\printbibliography` command.

The linked template suggests two possible approaches for citations and the bibliography.

- You can either manually curate your bibliography with `thebibliography` as in

  ```
  \begin{thebibliography}{}

  \bibitem[AUTHOR(YEAR)]{LABEL1}
  REFERENCE 1

  \bibitem[AUTHOR(YEAR)]{LABEL2}
  REFERENCE 2

  \end{thebibliography}
  ```

  See for example the "basic approach" in [this survey answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134180/35864).
- Or you can use a BibTeX-based approach.

If you have a `.bib` file, you will want to use a BibTeX-based solution. In that case, remove all references to `biblatex`, `\addbibresource` and `\printbibliography` from your document. Then place

```
\bibliographystyle{copernicus}
\bibliography{<your bib file name without file extension>}
```

where you want your bibliography to show up (where previously you had `\printbibliography` with `biblatex`).

The following is a fully working example document using the class with citations

```
\documentclass[sand, manuscript]{copernicus}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \citep{article-full}

\bibliographystyle{copernicus}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Note that a document like this needs to be compiled with BibTeX (and not with Biber, as `biblatex`-based documents). See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). Overleaf will do that for you automatically. If you compile on your own machine, you may have to tell your editor to do that.