# Bibliography not showing when compiled

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm trying to get my bibliography to print, but nothing seems to work. Here is a piece of my code, with all the packages that I have (sorry, it's kind of long):

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.85in,left=2.75in,footskip=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage[font=normal,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true,breaklinks=true,colorlinks,bookmarks=false]{hyperref}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=normal,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox} % it load graphicx too
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
%\MakeOuterQuote{"}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{makecell,   % new
            multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
% amsmath and amssymb packages, useful for mathematical formulas and symbols
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usepackage[natbib=true,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
  bibliography = {References},
}

% Use adjustwidth environment to exceed column width (see example table in text)
\usepackage{changepage}

% textcomp package and marvosym package for additional characters
\usepackage{textcomp,marvosym}

% cite package, to clean up citations in the main text. Do not remove.
\usepackage{cite}

% Use nameref to cite supporting information files (see Supporting Information section for more info)
\usepackage{nameref,hyperref}

% line numbers
\usepackage[right]{lineno}

% ligatures disabled
\usepackage[nopatch=eqnum]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = *, family = * }

% color can be used to apply background shading to table cells only
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

% array package and thick rules for tables
\usepackage{array}

% create "+" rule type for thick vertical lines
\newcolumntype{+}{!{\vrule width 2pt}}

% create \thickcline for thick horizontal lines of variable length
\newlength\savedwidth
\newcommand\thickcline[1]{%
  \noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 2pt}%
  \cline{#1}%
  \noalign{\vskip\arrayrulewidth}%
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}%
}

% \thickhline command for thick horizontal lines that span the table
\newcommand\thickhline{\noalign{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth 2pt}%
\hline
\noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}}


% Remove comment for double spacing
%\usepackage{setspace} 
%\doublespacing

% Text layout
\raggedright
\setlength{\parindent}{0.5cm}
\textwidth 5.25in 
\textheight 8.75in

% Bold the 'Figure #' in the caption and separate it from the title/caption with a period
% Captions will be left justified
\usepackage[aboveskip=1pt,labelfont=bf,labelsep=period,justification=raggedright,singlelinecheck=off]{caption}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig}

% Use the PLoS provided BiBTeX style
%\bibliographystyle{plos2015}

% Remove brackets from numbering in List of References
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@biblabel}[1]{\quad#1.}
\makeatother



% Header and Footer with logo
\usepackage{lastpage,fancyhdr,graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
%\pagestyle{myheadings}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\setlength{\headheight}{27.023pt}
%\lhead{\includegraphics[width=2.0in]{PLOS-submission.eps}}
\rfoot{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrule}{\hrule height 2pt \vspace{2mm}}
\fancyheadoffset[L]{2.25in}
\fancyfootoffset[L]{2.25in}
\lfoot{\today}

%% Include all macros below

\newcommand{\lorem}{{\bf LOREM}}
\newcommand{\ipsum}{{\bf IPSUM}}

%% END MACROS SECTION


\begin{document}
\vspace*{0.2in}

% Title must be 250 characters or less.
\begin{flushleft}
{\Large
\textbf\newline{Design and fabrication of carbon fiber lattices based on a looping techniques} % Please use "sentence case" for title and headings (capitalize only the first word in a title (or heading), the first word in a subtitle (or subheading), and any proper nouns).
}
\newline
% Insert author names, affiliations and corresponding author email (do not include titles, positions, or degrees).
\\
Hayley McClintock\textsuperscript{1*},
Zechen Xiong\textsuperscript{1},
Yibo Peng\textsuperscript{1},
David McIntosh\textsuperscript{1},
Yusong Deng\textsuperscript{1},
Hod Lipson\textsuperscript{1},
1
\\
\bigskip
\textbf{1} Columbia University, Fu Foundation School of Engineering and Applied Science, New York, NY, 10027, USA

\bigskip

% Insert additional author notes using the symbols described below. Insert symbol callouts after author names as necessary.
% 
% Remove or comment out the author notes below if they aren't used.
%
% Primary Equal Contribution Note


% Additional Equal Contribution Note
% Also use this double-dagger symbol for special authorship notes, such as senior authorship.



% Use the asterisk to denote corresponding authorship and provide email address in note below.
* hm2829@columbia.edu

\end{flushleft}

\section*{Abstract}

\bibliography{References}


\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you trim your code down please, there are too many unnecessary lines such as `\usepackage{subcaption}` that are not important to the question on bibliographies, just include the lines of code that cause your issue please

Comment: With `biblatex`, the command to print the bibliography is `\printbibliography` not `\bibliography`, could you change it to that and see if the issue is there please

Comment: also  have you run biber to  generate the bibliography? Please remove all the packages from the example apart from biblatex, they are unrelated to your question and make it _much_ harder for anyone to trace the code

Comment: also you must get errors from these packages, you load `caption`  and `xcolor` multiple times with conflicting options, you load `times`, `siunitx`, `textcomp`,`array`, `babel`,`subcaption`, `graphicx` !!!!!! multiple times, so you should delete  almost all lines of this preamble in your real documeny, not just the example here

Comment: Start with a simple examples like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134180/how-do-i-add-citations-at-the-end-of-the-document-as-done-here). Once you are able to reproduce theses examples, complete one only with that you really need, i.e., add `xcolor`package  only if you will need some text in color, `graphicx` only if you need to insert an image, and so on ...

Comment: I tried the \printbibliography and that might have worked, but now I'm getting an error saying "The 'cite' package and biblatex are incompatible." at the begin document line. I tried taking out the 'cite' package but that threw another error.

Comment: Fix a mess of code is usually much harder that, as said, start with a simple working example and then add (1) only with what you really need, and (2) do that step by step, Then, if some step produce a fatal error, then you can easily  go back and study why the last action break an example that was working.

Comment: If you want to use `biblatex` you must get rid of `\usepackage{cite}`. There is no way around this; the two packages are incompatible. If this breaks a different part of your document (which would surprise me because citations should be pretty broken if you load `biblatex` and `cite` together already), you need to analyse why carefully. Your preamble is so full of stuff, though, that it can be difficult to find out what is wrong. Can you not start from a truly minimal preamble and then only load what you actually need?