# Biblatex not printed & no number, only the citation key is bold

Tags: biblatex, citing, cite-package

I have a question regarding a bibliography which does not compile/only shows the citation key in the test as shown below:
[image]

My code for this is:

```
\documentclass{tudelft-report}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{report.bib}

\begin{document}

\input{TEXT}

%% Prevent urls running into margins in bibliography
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{7000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{7000}

%% Add bibliography
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,title=References]

\end{document}
```

Where my reference is given in the format, in **report.bib**:

```
@article{2020MeasurementModelling3D,
   author = {Kenji Araki and Yasuyuki Ota and Masafumi Yamaguchi},
   doi = {10.3390/app10030872},
   issn = {20763417},
   issue = {3},
   journal = {Applied Sciences (Switzerland)},
   keywords = {Car roof,Electric vehicles (EV),Flexible PV,Performance modeling,Photovoltaic,Plug-in hybrid vehicles (PHV),Rating,Standardization},
   month = {2},
   publisher = {MDPI AG},
   title = {Measurement and modeling of 3D solar irradiance for vehicle-integrated photovoltaic},
   volume = {10},
   year = {2020},
}
```

In addition, it does not print any bibliography. How can I then still obtain only the ["citation key"] instead of a number and no printed bibliography?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually bold keys are a sign that either Biber was not run at all or that Biber errorred so badly that no data could be produced. You need to compile your document with LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX (where "LaTeX" is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 for background. Most people use an editor for that, in which case you'll want to configure it as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. If you did run Biber and you still don't get the desired output, refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/286706/.

Comment: Also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) simple examples to test using biblatex and other alternatives, explained for completely novices.

Comment: Note that you've not given us the code to produce the problem you're seeing. If we run your code, we'll just get an error (unless we happen to have a `TEXT.tex` lying around in which case we'll get something completely different).

Comment: Any news here? As I said above, the most likely explanation given what you have shared so far is that you did not run Biber. If you have trouble getting Biber to run, please update your question and explain what you tried and how it did not work for you. If you did manage to run Biber and still don't get the desired output, please update your question and include the `.blg` file.

Comment: I voted to close as duplicate of our "how do I run Biber" question since that is the most likely explanation given the information shared so far. If you are still having trouble getting things to show the desired output, please ask a new question, but keep our comments in mind and try to address them when you formulate your new question.