# Show always only 1 author in references (APA Style)

Tags: cross-referencing, apa-style, apacite

I am writing my thesis in Overleaf and I would like to show always only 1 author in references (if there is more than 1 author). After the first author, to show "et al., YYYY" (APA style).

Currently, it shows like that in some cases, but not for all. I am not an expert in latex and I understand some of the packages importation order is incorrect. See how I have my code:

main.tex

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt, fleqn]{memoir}
\usepackage{format}
\usepackage[justification=centering, labelsep=period]{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{doi}
\usepackage{apacite} %APA style referencing
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{ragged2e} %for centering
\usepackage{float} %to avoid floating figures
\usepackage{booktabs} %merge columns
\usepackage{lscape} %vertical table
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

references.tex

```
\renewcommand{\bibname}{REFERENCES}

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{apacite} %APA style referencing
```

references.bib

```
@article{rn71,
author={Tattaris, Maria and Reynolds, Matthew P. and Chapman, Scott C.},
year={2016},
...
@article{rn70,
title = {Low-altitude, high-resolution aerial imaging systems for row and field crop phenotyping: A review},
author = {Sindhuja Sankaran and Lav R. Khot and Carlos Zúñiga Espinoza and Sanaz Jarolmasjed and Vidyasagar R. Sathuvalli and George J. Vandemark and Phillip N. Miklas and Arron H. Carter and Michael O. Pumphrey and N. Richard Knowles and Mark J. Pavek},
...
```

Current output:

[image]

Comment: The APA6 style implemented by `apacite` uses full names for first mention of authors up to 3 and "et al." subsequently. There's no trivial way to turn this off, but you can override it using the `\shortcites` commands. See [How to reduce the number of authors above >3 to 'First Author et al., (year)'?](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/383803).  Alternatively, you could switch to `biblatex` and then things get a little easier.

Comment: @AlanMunn can you provide an example on how to switch to biblatex? If it works I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604

Comment: [How can I implement a comprehensive apa-style citation and bibliography](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/352816) is a simple example. The `biblatex` implementation is of APA7 and I think you get this behaviour out of the box.

Comment: Why wouldn't you post the answer if you have it?