# Creating multiple bibliography using overleaf (multiple .bib files or separating using keywords)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overleaf, multibib, chapterbib

I'm learning to use latex, and so far, I have used the following in `main.tex` to create a bibliography:

```
\bibliography{main-bib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

and in text I use `\cite{referance}`

Now, in one chapter (separate .tex file), I want to use for a different bibliography, so I wrote something like this in `chapter.tex`:

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{\normalsize{Reference}} %change referance size to match the paper
\bibliography{chapter-bib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

My problem is that it no longer recognizes the rest of the references in the other chapters with the main bibliography `main-bib.bib` as they'll be marked with ? mark. So basically I want to treat the `chapter.tex` as a mini separate project (publication paper-like) with its own references.

I tried the following solutions with no success:
1- Add keywords to `main-bib.bib` to distinguish chapter references (only added to some references)

For example, in `main-bib.bib` I wrote the following:

```
@inproceedings{test123,
  title={title title,
  author={abce, abc},
  booktitle={booktitle},
  pages={31111},
  year={2018},
  organization={something},
keywords = {chapter}
}
```

And in the `chapter.tex`, I wrote the following:

```
\printbibliography[keyword={chapter},title={chapter ref}]
```

I got the following error: `Undefined control sequence.` Even with using `\printbibliography` on its own I guess it's not compatible somehow.

**How to add keywords using `\bibliography{main-bib}` ?**

2- using `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}` following the first solution here:
https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document

It worked for the `chapter.tex` but didn't works for the other chapters with separate .tex files as all in text citation would be marked with ? Instead if a number. Also, the title will change to bibliography instead of references, and I couldn't change it.

3- using `multibib` as in here: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Multibib
so I added

```
\usepackage[resetlabels,labeled]{multibib}
\newcites{paper}{Referances}
```

In `main.tex`, then in `chapter.tex`, I used `\citepaper{test}` and the following at the end:

```
\bibliographypaper{chapter-bib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrv}
```

This does absolutely nothing, no references can be shown for the paper.

I don't know what I did wrong following all of the above steps, I would kindly appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: At least with respect `\printbibliography` it seems that  you are mixing things without a clear  idea of what are you doing really. You must we aware of basic differences between use bitbex vs biber/biblatex (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604)). Then, using **only biblatex** approach, you can use some like `\newrefsegment \chapter{foo} ... \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
\newrefsegment` to print only the cites of chapter "foo".