# Reference style in paper

Tags: fonts, cross-referencing

is there a code to make the section of references of a paper look like this? i mean specifically the style of the authors name, as opposed to what follows after

[image]

Comment: It is not clear if you ask about [how to make a bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134182/11604) in general or only to obtain small caps for the authors, but  that depends on the method elected to make the bibliography (see the above link), so you should clarify that, preferably  with a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4408/11604).

Comment: You seem to ask how to make parts of the bibliography appear in small caps. But to answer this properly, it is necessary that you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your document setup.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{biblatex} %Imports biblatex package
\addbibresource{sample.bib} %Import the bibliography file

 \begin{document}
 Let's cite! Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and Dirac's book 
 \cite{dirac} are physics-related items. 

 \printbibliography %Prints bibliography
 \end{document}
```

**Check for reference:** https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX