# How to add 'title' in references using bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Its customary not to use title of the research article in Physics Journals refernces. I am currently writing a report where I need to add title of the articles. I do not want to use 'bibitem' to manually write the titles etc. Is there any bibliography style which produces references with titles along with author name, volume, year?

Comment: Almost all. What kind of Labels do you want? alphabetic? author/year? numeric?

Comment: Author Surname, Initials. Title of the article, Name of Journal, Volume No. (Issue No.), pages, Year.

Comment: Yeah, but the label that appears in the text, the marker that *marks* a citation and reappears in front of every bibitem.

Comment: Yes. That is alright. I don't want to cite title. 
What I want is to have the title of the journal printed along with the author name etc in the reference list. Most of the bibstyle say mn.bst (for MNRAS journal)  don't print title while listing the references.

Comment: @Johannes_B : Sorry for the trouble. I searched and found the answer here :
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132840/looking-for-a-template-which-reference-paper-has-a-title?rq=1